# Grabación de pantalla nativa android

Tags: android

Necesito crear una app en android nativa, la cual no te permita grabar la pantalla ni hacer capturas de pantalla.

Mirando la documentación he visto que para eso se usa `flag_secure`, y funciona sobre capturas de pantallas y aplicaciones externas de grabación de pantlla, pero cuando uso la que android trae por defecto no funciona.

En el onCreate de la función tengo esto

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.
 FLAG_SECURE ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el código de lo que tienes hecho?,  para que asi sea más facil dar una respuesta que sea acorde a lo que tratas de solucionar

Comment: Edita por favor tu pregunta, recuerda revisar [ask], saludos.